# How to display Laravel artisan command output on same line?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I would like to display processing progress using a simple series of dots. This is easy in the browser, just do `echo '.'` and it goes on the same line, but how do I do this on the same line when sending data to the artisan commandline?

Each subsequent call to `$this->info('.')` puts the dot on a new line.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The method *info* uses *writeln*, it adds a newline at the end, you need to use *write* instead.

```
//in your command
$this->output->write('my inline message', false);
$this->output->write('my inline message continues', false);
```

Comment: use `$this->command->getOutput()->write(//...` inside of a seeder

Answer (score 19):

Probably a little bit of topic, since you want a series of dots only. But you can easily present a progress bar in artisan commands using built in functionality in Laravel.

Declare a class variable like this:

```
protected $progressbar;
```

And initialize the progress bar like this, lets say in fire() method:

```
$this->progressbar = $this->getHelperSet()->get('progress');
$this->progressbar->start($this->output, Model::count());
```

And then do something like this:

```
foreach (Model::all() as $instance)
{
    $this->progressbar->advance(); //do stuff before or after this
}
```

And finilize the progress when done by calling this:

```
$this->progressbar->finish();
```

---

**Update: For Laravel 5.1+** The simpler syntax is even more convenient:

1. Initialize `$bar = $this->output->createProgressBar(count($foo));`
2. Advance `$bar->advance();`
3. Finish `$bar->finish();`

Comment: No problems, I was googling the same questions a while ago, and stumbled upon the progress bar solution, allthough poorly documented, if documented at all. Thought this answer might help someone find it faster, since it's a convenient way of presenting progress in a nice way.

Comment: Is there a way to display commandline output, such as with `$this->error()`, that will not disrupt the progressbar?

Comment: You can get a progressbar instance if >5.2 with `new \Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar($this->output)`

Comment: @eComEvo did you figure out a way to solve your problem? I am facing same issue

Answer (score 11):

If you look at the source, you will see that `$this->info` is actually just a shortcut for `$this->output->writeln`: [Source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php#L284).

You could use `$this->output->write('<info>.</info>')` to make it inline.

If you find yourself using this often you can make your own helper method like:

```
public function inlineInfo($string)
{
    $this->output->write("<info>$string</info>");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

\r is Carriage return
\n is Newline

So you can use:

```
echo "something\r";
```

to write in same line to display progress, for example. After that you can call "\n|

Comment: please pay attention to the question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).